# How to display third-party share buttons "inline-block" style using attribute selectors?

Tags: html, css, button, attributes, css-selectors

I'm attempting to style my third-party share buttons (code supplied by Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn) using attribute selectors. I currently have a set of styling rules allowing me to display these in an inline-block, as intended. However, each set of CSS properties relies on an exhaustive list of IDs - this is not efficient in any sense.

It seems I've tried everything, from applying using classes as selectors and so on, and nothing seems to work. I thought maybe attribute selectors may be the way to go, but have been having trouble there as well.

This is what I've tried thus far, to no avail:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.tylercharboneauprofessional.com/international-pulse/your-guide-to-the-french-election/" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="false"></div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button social-share" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script><script type="IN/Share"></script>

<style> [class|="fb"] { display: inline-block; } </style>
<style> [class|="twitter"] { display: inline-block; } </style>
<style> [class|="IN"] { display: inline-block; } </style>
```

For Dev Tools purposes: www.tylercharboneauprofessional.com

I would like to decrease the size of my CSS file by about 1/4.

Comment: can you add the html structure of the elements

Comment: add your html please, we can't tell you what CSS to use to target the elements if you don't show us the html.

Comment: Hey all, question has been edited and code has been added above.